# Can a PDFLaTeX file contain a random number based on the end user?

Tags: pdftex, random-numbers

Suppose I want to design a math exam to be posted as a single PDF file, for example one asking students to solve $ax^2+bx+c=0$. But I want each student who gets the PDF file to see a different set of $a,b,c$ values upon opening their files. Is such a thing possible?

For example, can a random seed that is taken from the time of opening of the file  or some factor related to the computer of the recipient set the values of  $a,b,c$?

And in addition, I prefer that the seed is generated only once, so that on the second reopening of the same file the student sees what s/he saw the first time. Is this possible?

What is the preferred/easier alternative to PDF?

EDIT:

I realized that the scheme is not safe. In the sense that a student can write any  convenient $abc$ and claim that that is the random number generated for him!

So here is a modification: Student enters his ID number in a form field and presses a button. Out comes $a,b,c$.  This will be reproducible and each student gets a different set and upon reloading the same numbers will show.

Would the resulting PDF be a security issue or one that will exhibit many compatibility problems?

Comment: It is possible to make from one (1) exam source more than one  hundred (>100)  exams in a single PDF, were  in each exam copy the equation is randomly different, but the only way to change the PDF contents is compiling again. If this is acceptable for you, see this [simple example of AMC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238799/11604).

Comment: If you are prepared to use JavaScript and Adobe reader you can use form fields. But this will not give you nice maths. I don't think this is a good option though.

Comment: @Fran in the answer you have linked to there is a package called "automultiplechoice". I do not see it listed under packages on MiKTeX.

Comment: @Maesumi AMC Is not only a package, is not in CTAN. See [here](https://www.auto-multiple-choice.net/).  And is not for Window, but see  [here](https://project.auto-multiple-choice.net/projects/auto-multiple-choice/wiki/Using_AMC_on_a_PC_without_Linux_(with_a_live-USB_key)) for alternatives.

Comment: @DavidPurton  An edit is made to the question. Does this work JavaScript?

Comment: Each student must buy Adobe Acrobat Pro in order to process your PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `eforms` package. This isn't part of TeXLive, but is in MikTeX. It's possible to get it from CTAN and install it in your local TeX tree if you're using TeXLive.

I think you'll need to write your own random number generator so that you can seed it with a student number. I used code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593316/12652399).

This isn't very sensitive to the seed, so you would want to adjust how you get the final numbers or use a more suitable random number generator. I'm not really a maths guy, so this is left as an exercise for the reader…

This will *only* work with Adobe Reader. Virtually no other PDF viewer supports JavaScript.

To use it, enter a student number (e.g., 987654) and click the button. You'll get the same three numbers each time. If you enter a different student number, you'll get a different set of three numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eforms}

% Pseudo random number generator code taken from
% https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593316/12652399
\begin{defineJS}{\genNums}
  function sfc32(a, b, c, d) {
    return function() {
      a >>>= 0; b >>>= 0; c >>>= 0; d >>>= 0; 
      var t = (a + b) | 0;
      a = b ^ b >>> 9;
      b = c + (c << 3) | 0;
      c = (c << 21 | c >>> 11);
      d = d + 1 | 0;
      t = t + d | 0;
      c = c + t | 0;
      return (t >>> 0) / 4294967296;
    }
  }
  var txtId = this.getField("txtId");
  var seed = Number(txtId.value) ^ 0xDEADBEEF;
  var rand = sfc32(seed, seed, seed, seed);
  var txtA = this.getField("txtA");
  var txtB = this.getField("txtB");
  var txtC = this.getField("txtC");
  txtA.value = rand();
  txtB.value = rand();
  txtC.value = rand();
\end{defineJS}

\begin{document}

Student number: \textField{txtId}{3cm}{11bp}
\pushButton[\CA{Generate Numbers}\A{\JS{\genNums}}]{btnRun}{}{11bp}

a: \textField{txtA}{5cm}{11bp}

b: \textField{txtB}{5cm}{11bp}

c: \textField{txtC}{5cm}{11bp}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Great!  By the way, regarding the random number generator,  I just noticed as I change the student number slightly the random number changes slightly. Which is odd. But that is a separate issue.

Comment: @Maesumi, yes that's what I mean when I say the random numbers are not very sensitive to the seed. But I don't have the maths to know the right kind of random number generator.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `random.tex` which enables generation of random numbers. A simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{random}
\begin{document}
\nextrandom  % generate a random number as \randomi
\the\randomi % print the random number
\end{document}
```

Read the manual `texdoc random` for more information.

**EDIT**

I suggest that you run LaTeX on your file once for each of your students. They will then get a PDF file with unique random numbers. 15 students you generate 15 PDF files. You would need to record to which students you sent their unique PDF file.

Comment: With this approach, the random number gets generated when the pdf is created and then remains fixed. If I understand the OP correctly, the question is whether the number can be generated anew each time the pdf is opened.

Comment: @gernot As I understand it the OP's problem could be resolved by getting each student to run LaTeX on the source file to produce their PDF with unique random numbers. Otherwise the question is directed at PDF viewers. Person A views a PDF file which has a random number and person B views the "same" PDF file with a different random number but if A later views the PDF file it has the same random number when viewed previously. I have no idea if this is possible; have you?

Comment: I don't know the pdf format very well, so I can't answer the original question. The comment by David Purton hints at JavaScript in PDF forms as a (fragile) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I write multiple letters including deductions which depend on the addressee of the letter. To that end I use one letter and get different data via the [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package. If you have 100 students you need probably not 100 different, but maybe 50 different sets of questions.